# How to display a single thumbnail for multiple human faces?

Tags: website-design, web-app, tables, interface

I have a multi-row table view where an image represent the people who are associated with the row. Each row can have n number of people. How may I show a single thumbnail when members are more than one person?

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using a grid of images within the thumbnail? How many members belong to an "image group"? A large part of this is context of the problem. Do you have to show a photo of an individual to convey the meaning of the group, or would some kind of icon designed to show a general attribute of the group suffice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A stacked group with the face of the last submitter is what I would consider.  With the ability to expand the stack and see all involved.

[image: Stacked user group collapsed and expanded]

Comment: I like this. The icon changes when new people join, so it's not just one person's photo the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create smaller thumbnails depending on the number of members. For instance if there are 2 people, you can generate two smaller thumbnails. Like this, you can generate a maximum of 4 thumbnails. If the number of people is greater than 4, you can show 3 image thumbnails and the 4th one can contain a number e.g +1, +2 to represent the additional members.

[image]

Comment: Google Hangout chooses this way. With circles though.

Answer (score 1):

If a (possibly sliding) image-row is not an option and you need to show all users you could consider a single morphing thumbnail showing all of them.

[image]

(Better without causing people epileptic seizures)